# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting on windows server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, dll

In my local machine when i ran my application i am successfully able to load the page and i deploy the same code in windows server 2008 and i am getting the below error

"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

visual studio not installed in my server.

I think we need to register that assembly on the windows server 2008. How can i resolve this error on windows server 2008 without visual studio command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is by installing this nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
```

which contains System.Net.Http.Formatting (and make sure you deploy it).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "Copy local" setting to "True" in Visual Studio reference properties for that assembly and deploy again.